# Admob not showing production ad on test device(using flutter)

Tags: flutter, admob

I am using the google_mobile_ads plugin to show banner ads on the test device. When I use a adunit test ID from google it shows just fine, but when I set my device as a test device on admob and tried to show the production ads it wont show and there is a stack that says the following:

```
D/DynamitePackage(27713): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads (27713): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("some_random_alhanumeric_characters_i_dont_know_if_I_should_show_it")) to get test ads on this device.
I/DynamiteModule(27713): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:210402101
```

Comment: use real device not emulator

Comment: yes, Im actually using real device